# How to distribute files via SFTP in read-only, without root permission, without password prompt and restricting directory access?

Tags: sftp

How can I distribute some files to everyone without password via SFTP protocol in read-only restricting directory access without the need of root permissions/chroot? I prefer to not use software that isn't commonly available in GNU/Linux distributions.

Openssh seems to require root permission for chrooting the directory.

Comment: `sshd` does not refuse to run as a non root user. However it will fail calling `setuid()` and every SFTP user will run with your credentials.

Comment: @Piotrp.karwasz I think there will be another problem as well - sshd will not be able to bind to a port below 1024 without root, so an alternative port will need to be set as well.

Comment: Yes, I did try on port `2222`. Many PAM modules failed (notably **pam_unix**, but not **pam_krb5** which does not need root priviledges), but I was able to login as myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved forking https://github.com/pkg/sftp to https://github.com/amreo/sftp.git and adding the required features.

Example: https://github.com/amreo/ercole-services/blob/master/repo-service/service/sftp.go